# JS select2 plugin not scrolling when options are open

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I am using JS Select2 library to use as multiple options select. The select is positioned within a `div` which is scrolled by its parent `div` with `css` - `overflow-y: scroll`. The nested `div` scrolls fine until an option is opened. When options are opened then the `div` becomes un-scrollable *unless* it is scrolled on the select options. Not sure if the source of the problem is my html/css or its the `select2` lib.

Thanks in advance for any help!

My markup:

```
<div id="topcontainer" style="padding-top: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;  position: absolute; height: 1000px; width: 500px; background: #6d3353">
<div id="parent" style="position: relative; height: 3000px; width: 200px; background: #e4b9b9">
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AL">aaaaaaa</option>
        <option value="AL">bbbbbbb</option>
        <option value="AL">ccccccc</option>
        <option value="WY">ddddddd</option>
    </select>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Select2 intercept the scroll as you can see in the [select2 source code](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/d1a57156f79ae7e614c0b2fa6158aad84f0d6955/dist/js/select2.full.js).

I think its not a problem but a feature, because when you have it opened you want to scroll it, not the parents.

Anyway, looking at [select2 events](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) I found that we can override it by using the "**select2:open**" event and removing the added 
"**scroll.select2**" namespace events.

Example:

```
     $('#states').select2({
         dropdownParent: $('#parent')
      });
      $('#states').on('select2:open', function (e) {
        const evt = "scroll.select2";
        $(e.target).parents().off(evt);
        $(window).off(evt);
      });
```

You may test it here: [Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/salecih/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, worked like a charm!
 You're said that "_you want to scroll it, not the parents._" but in my case, with your solution behaves as a nested scroll which is exactly what I need. Excellent!